# Cesàro Mean Convergence Proof

Tags: real-analysis

I have been given the following proof that if the sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then the sum $\frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}$ also converges to $a$:

**Proof.*
The sequence $(a_n)$ must be bounded. Let $|a_n| \leq M$ for all $n$. Given $\epsilon >0$ pick $N$ such that $\forall n \geq N$: $$|a_n - a| < \epsilon.$$
It follows that for all $n \geq N$ we have $$\left|\left(\frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}\right) - a
\right| \leq \frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_k - a|} = \frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}|a_k - a|} + \frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=N}^{n}|a_k - a|} \leq \frac{2(N-1)M}{n} + \frac{(n-N+1)\epsilon}{n}.$$
Here $M$ and $N$ are fixed. We let $n \to \infty$. The first term goes to zero, while the second term is less than $\epsilon$. Hence for all very large $n$ we have
$$\left|\left(\frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}\right) - a
\right| < 2\epsilon.$$
From this the claim follows.*

My question is, where does the $2$ in the term $\frac{2(N-1)M}{n}$ come from?

My attempt at finding a bound for $\frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}|a_k - a|}$ goes as follows:

*Since $(a_n)$ converges, it is bounded. So there is $M_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|a_n| \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. By the triangle inequality
$$|a_n - a| = |a_n + (-a)| \leq |a_n| + |(-a)| = |a_n| + |a| \leq M_0 + |a|.$$
Letting $M = M_0 + |a|$ we have that
$$\frac{1}{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}|a_k - a|} \leq \frac{(N-1)M}{n}.$$*

So my answer differs by a factor of $2$. Have they included the $2$ for a particular reason? How have they come up with it? It still follows from my answer, I could multiply by $2$ and end up with the same thing but is there any reason I might do so?

Is my reasoning correct or have I made a mistake that accounts for this difference?

I understand that it doesn't matter how large or small the bound is in this case so the difference is inconsequential. Just wondering if I'm missing something important.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the meaning of $M$. The $M$ seen in the published proof is the upper bound on $a_n$; that is, $M$ is chosen to satisfy $|a_n|\le M$ for all $n$. And since $|a_n|$ converges to $|a|$, it must be true that $|a|\le M$ also. Hence $|a_k-a|\le |a_k|+|a|\le 2M$. This explains the $2M$ in the published proof.

Your proof is really the same as the published proof, except for notation. In your proof you use $M_0$ as the upper bound on $|a_n|$. Your $M$ is $M_0 + |a|$. But $|a|\le M_0$ by the same reasoning as above. Hence you could have taken $M:=2M_0$, and you'll have a factor of two.